# as3: MOUSE_OVER is slow/not working correctly

Tags: actionscript-3

Okay so I'm working in pure as3 (no creative suite or xml). I have a sprite. It draws a large rectangle and then a slightly smaller rectangle. I want to change the color of the slightly smaller rectangle when I hover the mouse over it. Right now though it will either not respond (I can plainly have the mouse over the rectangle and nothing happens) or it is slow to respond. In addition the collision area of the rectangle seems a bit off, ie it responds more frequently when I have the mouse on the upper left corner of the rectangle than when I have the mouse elsewhere on it.

Anyways here's the code I'm using:

```
public function MAIN()
        {
   BUTTON_1.graphics.clear();
   BUTTON_1.graphics.beginFill(0x000000);
   BUTTON_1.graphics.drawRect(188,96,104,24);
   BUTTON_1.graphics.endFill();
   BUTTON_1.graphics.beginFill(0x0000DC);
   BUTTON_1.graphics.drawRect(190,98,100,20);
   BUTTON_1.graphics.endFill();
   addChild(BUTTON_1);
   BUTTON_1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER,MOUSE_OVER_1);
   function MOUSE_OVER_1():void
   {
    removeChild(BUTTON_1);
    BUTTON_1.graphics.clear();
    BUTTON_1.graphics.beginFill(0x000000);
    BUTTON_1.graphics.drawRect(188,96,104,24);
    BUTTON_1.graphics.endFill();
    BUTTON_1.graphics.beginFill(0x0000A0);
    BUTTON_1.graphics.drawRect(190,98,100,20);
    BUTTON_1.graphics.endFill();
    addChild(BUTTON_1);
   }
}
```

I'm pretty new to as3 so if there's a better way to do this tell me.

Comment: Yeah sorry about that, I went through and accepted any good answers that I got. Anyways I figured it out, I didn't realize you could use hitTestPoint with sprites which works just fine.

Comment: If you solve your own problem, you can post your own answer below.  You can then accept your own answer to let others know that your problem has been solved.  Sometimes there's a bit of delay before you're allowed to accept in case you were mistaken, but it should let you do it eventually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using hitTestPoint, like this:

```
        if (BUTTON_1.hitTestPoint(mouseX,mouseY,true)) 
        {   

            removeChild(BUTTON_1);
            removeChild(TEXT_MENU_1);
            BUTTON_1.graphics.clear();
            BUTTON_1.graphics.beginFill(0x000000);
            BUTTON_1.graphics.drawRect(188,96,104,24);
            BUTTON_1.graphics.endFill();
            BUTTON_1.graphics.beginFill(0x0000A0);
            BUTTON_1.graphics.drawRect(190,98,100,20);
            BUTTON_1.graphics.endFill();
            addChild(BUTTON_1);
            addChild(TEXT_MENU_1);
        }
        else
        {
            removeChild(BUTTON_1);
            removeChild(TEXT_MENU_1);
            BUTTON_1.graphics.clear();
            BUTTON_1.graphics.beginFill(0x000000);
            BUTTON_1.graphics.drawRect(188,96,104,24);
            BUTTON_1.graphics.endFill();
            BUTTON_1.graphics.beginFill(0x0000DC);
            BUTTON_1.graphics.drawRect(190,98,100,20);
            BUTTON_1.graphics.endFill();
            addChild(BUTTON_1);
            addChild(TEXT_MENU_1);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

this code doesn't seem correct. listener for mouse events takes MouseEvent object as parameter. So your MOUSE_OVER_1 should be like `function MOUSE_OVER_1(e:MouseEvent):void`.

Comment: Actually that's not a problem.  Since `MOUSE_OVER_1` is a nested function, it won't have its parameters checked.  Nested functions are treated identically to top-defined local vars of type `Function`.